# Excel: How to Hyperlink a cell based on a changing sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

My first post here :)

To keep things simple, I currently have 2 sheets in Excel, these are:

- MAIN_MENU
- BLANK_PROJ

I have a VBA script (Macro assigned to a button) that is displayed in my MAIN_MENU sheet as 'Create a New Project'. When this button is clicked the following happens:

1. The Macro runs and it copies the BLANK_PROJ sheet and creates a new sheet called 'BLANK_PROJ(2)' **WORKS AS EXPECTED**
2. In BLANK_PROJ(2) I am then prompted to enter a Project ID (consisting of a 4 digit number, i.e. 1234). I enter this in the relevant cell in the BLANK_PROJ(2) sheet. **WORKS AS EXPECTED**
3. On the same BLANK_PROJ(2) sheet a few other cells are automatically populated, i.e. 'Project Code', Project Name' etc. **WORKS AS EXPECTED**
4. The Macro then renames this BLANK_PROJ(2) sheet with a value taken from a given cell in the same sheet (i.e. it is renamed to PROJ_01, or PROJ_02, PROJ_03, etc). **WORKS AS EXPECTED**
5. The Macro then switches sheets and goes to my MAIN_MENU sheet and inserts the newly created sheet name (this was originally BLANK_PROJ(2) as mentioned in step 1 above, but now has a new name as per step number 4 above, for example 'PROJ_01') It inserts the name exactly where I would like it in the Menu. **WORKS AS EXPECTED**
6. **By now the Macro has copied a sheet, renamed the copied sheet and
   placed the new name in my Main Menu list - all good up till here,
   the next bit is what I am finding challenging**
7. The name that has been copied into my Menu list, i.e. 'PROJ_01', I would like this to be hyperlinked so when clicked on it takes me to the relevant sheet, in this case 'PROJ_01' sheet. **UNSURE HOW TO ACHIEVE THIS**
8. If I repeat steps 1 to 6 above and get another menu item in my MAIN_MENU sheet then I want it to always link to the corresponding sheet, without me having to manually hyperlink each new item that lands in my MAIN_MENU sheet.

So it's Point Number 7 that I am struggling with - I just need someone out there who understands the above and kindly provide a line of code that will do the trick for me that I can add in my VB script.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create hyperlinks using vba. Refer this website it would guide you how to do it.
https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-hyperlinks/

Comment: Thank you Anmol Kumar - I will take a look and see how I get on. Appreciate your help.